# TypeScript plugin for Visual Studio 2012 gives an error immediately

Tags: typescript

I downloaded and installed the TypeScript [plugin for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) and then Visual Studio 2012 wouldn't even start.  It immediately gave a message box '.. target of an invocation...' error.

I had to un-install the plugin to be able to use Visual Studio 2012 again.

Anyone have similar experience and is there a fix ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well.  For me, it was due to my Windows PATH variable going over 2047 characters.  This also broke the %windir% path expansion, so I was unable to edit my PATH variable by going to Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.  The solution was to edit my System PATH variable by going to C:\Windows\system32\ and running systempropertiesadvanced.exe, copying the System PATH variable out of there, paste it into your text editor of choice, split it on the semicolon, sort it alphabetically, delete duplicates and other unneeded paths until I get below 2047 characters, rejoin all lines with a semicolon, and paste it back into my System PATH variable.  See [this](http://blog.customizedev.com/index.php/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problems and the only one I have come across is that the templates can't be found after install.

The only suggestion I have is to re-attempt the install and see if you get a different result. If you still get an error, please supply the whole error message.

**Update**

Okay, here are some other things to try - I have put them in order of how painful they are!

1. I don't know where you are installing TypeScript from, but a colleague mentioned that they had a problem and resolved it by moving the installer to the desktop to run the install. I am sceptical about this one, but it is easy to do.
2. You may have a problem with your Visual Studio installation that is only manifesting itself in certain situations. You could repair your VS installation.

If none of this works, you may have to raise an issue on http://typescript.codeplex.com

Comment: Same thing after trying to install again.

Comment: [Microsoft Visual Studio]
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: And when you click OK on the error dialog, Visual Studio never opens.  I might add this is on Windows 7 - 64 bit machine.

Comment: I have the same set up. I have added two further options.