# TypeScript 0.9.1.1.exe crashes my visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I installed the TypeScriptSetup.0.9.1.1.exe today, and after that I was not able to run my visual studio. Upon running it gives the following error.

"Exception was thrown by the target of invocation"

that then the visual studio doesn't start.

Once this error comes, I have to restart the computer just to run the setup to uninstall the TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20483413/71262):

I ran into this issue as well.  For me, it was due to my Windows PATH variable going over 2047 characters.  This also broke the %windir% path expansion, so I was unable to edit my PATH variable by going to Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.  The solution was to edit my System PATH variable by going to C:\Windows\system32\ and running systempropertiesadvanced.exe, copying the System PATH variable out of there, paste it into your text editor of choice, split it on the semicolon, sort it alphabetically, delete duplicates and other unneeded paths until I get below 2047 characters, rejoin all lines with a semicolon, and paste it back into my System PATH variable.  See [this](http://blog.customizedev.com/index.php/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation/) for more info.

Comment: yup that was the issue in my case. I fixed it using the same method before your answer but I can confirm this was the issue and I fixed it as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have uninstalled web essentials. OR updated web essentials to 3.x (which removed typescript support). There are known memory issues before that version.

Comment: No, this doesnt seems to be the problem. Tried both without it and installing 3.0 same result.

Comment: I am also on Update 3 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: I'm also on latest Web Essentials, VS2012 update 3, and getting regular VS crashes when editing Typescript files... so I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: Another issue is with the MySQL connector visual studio integration plugin